# Additive functors preserve split exact sequences

Tags: homological-algebra

How can I prove that additive functors preserve split exact sequences?

Comment: Prove that a split exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ is isomorphic to the obvious direct sum sequence $0 \to A \to A \oplus C \to C \to 0$.

Comment: (Prove also that a functor is additive if and only if it preserves 0 and binary direct sums.)

Comment: @ZhenLin Please consider converting your comment (and the comment by t.b.) into a (hint only) answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 16):

I am assuming we are dealing with a functor $F: R\mathrm{Mod} \to S\mathrm{Mod}$ where $R$ and $S$ are commutative rings, although the result may hold in more general settings that I am not sufficiently familiar with.

A split exact sequence $0 \to A \xrightarrow{i} B \xrightarrow{p} C \to 0$ can be characterized by 4 functions and 5 equations:
\begin{align}
i &: A \to B, \\
q &: B \to A, \\
j &: C \to B, \\
p &: B \to C, \\
q \circ i &= 1_A, \\
p \circ j &= 1_C, \\
p \circ i &= 0, \\
q \circ j &= 0, \\
i \circ q + j \circ p &= 1_B.
\end{align}
That is, the given sequence is split exact if and only if there are $j$ and $q$ so that $i, j, p, q$ satisfy the above equations.
Now any functor preserves composition and identity, and additive functors also preserve addition and the 0 morphism, so the entire characterization of the split exact sequence is preserved, and hence its image is split exact.

Comment: Relevant: the data $i,q,j,p$ along with the relations you've stated is also precisely what characterizes a *direct sum* in a preadditive category: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0103

Answer (score 2):

Let $F:\mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ be an additive functor between abelian categories. A chain complex is split exact if and only if the identity map is null-homotopic (Weibel Exercise 1.4.3). 
Let $1_\mathcal{A}$ be the identity mapping from the chain complex $0\to A \stackrel{d}{\to} B \stackrel{d}{\to} C \to 0$ to itself, and $1_\mathcal{B}$ the identity mapping on $0\to F(A) \stackrel{F(d)}{\to} F(B) \stackrel{F(d)}{\to} F(C) \to 0$. Since the first sequence is split exact, we can find a chain contraction $s$ such that $1_\mathcal{A}=ds+sd$. Applying $F$ to both sides, we obtain $F(1_\mathcal{A})= 1_\mathcal{B} = F(d)F(s)+F(s)F(d)$. So the target sequence must also be split exact.